# How can I show the number of App Store Downloads within my iOS or Android App?

Tags: android, ios

We are building a social media application which is heavy on promotion. As a promotional tool, we would like to show the number of downloads to app users within the app itself. Is it possible to do this with iOS or Android?

Comment: Not  a good question to ask on stack overflow. But besides that, you could just manually put that number in your cloud server (if you use one) and query it on client side. Then whenever you hit a milestone, just manually put For example `10,000+` in your cloud server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS I'll say likely.  You can use the [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi) to download sales reports:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports

Then you can parse through the report and display your number of downloads within your application.

[Here is a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350351/is-it-possible-to-get-number-of-downloads-of-an-application-from-google-play) that offers various answers for Google Play Store.